# How to sort a dict by values and return a list of formatted strings?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, string-formatting

I've got a dict:

```
text_to_count = { "text1": 1, "text2":0, "text3":2}
```

I'd like to create a list of formatted strings by sorting this dict's values (in descending order).

I.e., I like following list:

```
result = ["2 - text3", "1 - text1", "0 - text2"]
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

While waiting for responses, I kept hacking at it and came up with:

```
result = map(lambda x: "{!s} - {!s}".format(x[1], x[0]), 
                       sorted(text_to_count.iteritems(), 
                       key = lambda(k, v): (v, k), reverse=True ))
```

Tho I'm still interested in seeing what other solutions there are, possibly one better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

```
result = ['{1} - {0}'.format(*pair) for pair in sorted(text_to_count.iteritems(), key = lambda (_,v): v, reverse = True)]
```

Comment: I went with this one since I don't have to import 'operator'

Comment: @Cuga: For further reading about the `string.format()` function, see the [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Answer (score 2):

```
['%d - %s' % (v, k) for (k, v) in sorted(text_to_count.iteritems(),
    key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)]
```

Comment: @Jeff, yours is still good too-- you taught me .format(*... I had not seen that before.  Is there any comparison for speed?

Comment: @Cuga: Not to my knowledge.  Negligible AFAIK.  As I understand it, it was meant to be a more flexible alternative to using the `%` operator.

Comment: I see.  Any comparison overall between ur answer, mine, and Ignacio's?

Answer (score 0):

And one more, codegolf style:

```
>>> ['%s - %s'%(t[x],x) for x in sorted(t,key=t.get)[::-1]]
['2 - text3', '1 - text1', '0 - text2']
```

PS. to illustrate a point brought by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams comment, note how the sorts results can vary if there are value repeats:

```
>>> t={'txt1':1, 'txt2':0, 'txt3':1}
>>> ['%s - %s'%(t[x],x) for x in sorted(t,key=t.get)[::-1]]
```

['1 - **txt3**', '1 - **txt1**', '0 - txt2']

```
>>> ['%s - %s'%(t[x],x) for x in sorted(t,key=t.get,reverse=True)]
```

['1 - **txt1**', '1 - **txt3**', '0 - txt2']

Comment: Note that reversing after sorting may not necessarily have the same result as reversing *while* sorting, since Python's sort is stable.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: thanks for the note, was amusing to think over it a bit. I agree - reversing the sort result won't necessarily return the same result as `reverse=True` for the case when there are multiple values of the same kind. But it well satisfies the question (there is no requirement of specific order when values are the same).